# Trying to match two " ArrayList<Point> "

Tags: java, arraylist, point

I am trying to find the percentage of how many elements in two `ArrayList<Point>`s match, but I am at a dead end. Can anyone help?

This is what I tried to do, I don't know if it's true or applicable:

```
int i;
int count = 0;

ArrayList<Point> firstInter= array1; //  output from other class
ArrayList<Point> secondInter = array2; //output from other class
int size= firstInter.size(); //they have the same size

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (firstInter.get(i) == secondInter.get(i)) {
        count1++;
    }
}

double percentage1 = count / size;
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Without a question, no one can answer it!

Comment: @jpaugh he's looking for the intersection of two lists.

Comment: Yes. But I was hoping the  OP could tell more specifically what's wrong with the code he has.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the intersection of both lists. In detail: The number of elements of the first list that are also contained in the second list:

```
List<Point> first = ...;
List<Point> second = ...;
int count = 0;

for (Point p : first) {
    if (second.contains(p)) count++;
}

// assuming, first and second have equal size
double percentage = (double)count / first.size();
```

Containment operations are much more efficient in a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) than a `List`, so if you have a lot of elements, it might be considerably faster, to use a `Set` for `second`:

```
Set<Point> second = new HashSet<Point>(secondList);
```

Fortunately, a `Set` already offers a method to perform an intersection operation: `Set.retainAll(Collection other)`. [Java API Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-):

> Retains only the elements in this set that are contained in the
>   specified collection (optional operation).

So to get the intersection of two collections, we can simply use this method:

```
Collection<Point> first = ...; // should be a Set for maximum performance
Set<Point> second = new HashSet<Point>(...);

second.retainAll(first);

// assuming, both point lists have equal size
double percentage = (double)count / first.size();
```

*Note: All this code only works if class `Point` has correctly overwritten `equals` and `hashcode`. See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java._)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `intersection` from: `org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils`:

```
int intersectionSize = CollectionUtils.intersection(firstInter, secondInter).size();
```

As for "percentage", the question is percentage of what? the union ? Either way it shouldn't be difficult, you can do something like:

```
return 100 * intersectionSize / (firstInter.size() + secondInter.size());
```